# JPA - Dois relacionamentos OneToOne e OneToMany entre as mesmas classe

Tags: sql, jpa, relacionamento

Eu possuo uma classe Estudante e ela tem dois relacionamentos com `Pessoa` um `OneToOne` e `OneToMany` e pessoa por sua vez um relacionamento com `Endereco`, como mostrado abaixo:

Classe Estudante

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ESTUDANTE")
public class Estudante implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1335678886512650803L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA", referencedColumnName = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA_CADASTRO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private PessoaFisica cadastrante;

  //Get & Set

}
```

Classe Pessoa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA_FISICA")
public class PessoaFisica implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6877588433120679748L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private long codigo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pessoaFisica")
    private Estudante estudante;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cadastrante")
    private List<Estudante> listaEstudanteCadastrados;    

  //Get & Set
```

Um estudante é uma pessoa (OneToOne), e ele também ao ser cadastrado recebe a informação de quem fez esse cadastro (`OneToMany`). O problema esta na hora que o `JPA` gera o `SQL`, pois ele esta utilizando o relacionamento `OneToMany` para ligar com a tabela endereço ao invés de usar o relacionamento de `OneToOne`.

```
select
        this_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA as ID1_7_7_,
        pessoafis3_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA as PFIS1_8_0_,
        endereco5_.ID_ENDERECO as EPES2_9_,
        pessoafis10_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA as PFIS1_8_6_,
    from
        ESTUDANTE this_,
        PESSOAS_FISICAS pessoafis3_,
        ENDERECO endereco5_,
        PESSOAS_FISICAS pessoafis10_ 
    where
        this_.ID_PESSOA_CADASTRO=pessoafis3_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA(+) 
        and epessoafis3_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA=endereco5_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA(+) 
        and this_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA=pessoafis10_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA(+) 
    order by
        this_.ID_PESSOA_FISICA desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma com que está, esse seu `@OneToOne` entre `Estudante` e `PessoaFisica` não faz muito sentido, até porque não necessariamente uma pessoa é um estudante, e um cadastrante também não deveria ser um estudante.

Eu faria `Estudante` herdar de `PessoaFisica` usando a *annotation* [`Inheritance`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.1.0/apache-openjpa-1.1.0/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE, discriminatorValue="P")
@Table(name = "PESSOA_FISICA")
public class PessoaFisica implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6877588433120679748L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private long codigo;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cadastrante")
    private List<Estudante> listaEstudanteCadastrados;    

  //Get & Set
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(discriminatorValue="E")
public class Estudante extends PessoaFisica 
{
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA", referencedColumnName = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA_CADASTRO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
    private PessoaFisica cadastrante;

  //Get & Set

}
```

Não testei este código, mas seria mais ou menos isso. É possível ainda separar o cadastrante em uma classe também derivada de `PessoaFisica`.

Comment: Eu verifiquei esse erro é realmente não faz sentido, removi esse relacionamento a mais e encontrei a solução forçando o relacionamento @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) dessa forma o SQL foi criado corretamente.
Obrigado pela atenção!